# Whay are these same Youtube API REST urls returning different results?

Tags: youtube-api

My code uses this URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&snippet&id=UC9ctsJZ2aD1nCexfqj342NQ&key=[API_KEY]`
which returns

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "69nKH4yrkGqjpjRH2T_M86dyIUI",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "A0IqlEsff608TjGHRdSAoqyeaiw",
      "id": "UC9ctsJZ2aD1nCexfqj342NQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

The sample code at `https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list`
has this call

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2C%20snippet&id=UC9ctsJZ2aD1nCexfqj342NQ&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

And it returns the data I'm expecting:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "oMV3kRZIiTu9TJSfDOaPpFGwsV0",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "-XETGcPmF-U5W8ONzQEJ9R8w-OI",
      "id": "UC9ctsJZ2aD1nCexfqj342NQ",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Better Bachelor",
        "description": "Better Bachelor is a channel for open minded men (and women if so inclined) to talk about current events, news, opinions, humor and ways to better yourself and find happiness and understanding in today's society. This is an open forum where comments, talking points, concerns and discussion about topics are encouraged. Most content is focused towards single men's issues but may be applicable to others. I focus on viewing many issues from multiple or under represented angles.",
        "customUrl": "@betterbachelor",
        "publishedAt": "2019-02-08T10:23:44Z",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu9WcURyY8M4f-RKmm8LrlneJjRxEcPeKhfefPeXXA=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "width": 88,
            "height": 88
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu9WcURyY8M4f-RKmm8LrlneJjRxEcPeKhfefPeXXA=s240-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "width": 240,
            "height": 240
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu9WcURyY8M4f-RKmm8LrlneJjRxEcPeKhfefPeXXA=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "width": 800,
            "height": 800
          }
        },
        "localized": {
          "title": "Better Bachelor",
          "description": "Better Bachelor is a channel for open minded men (and women if so inclined) to talk about current events, news, opinions, humor and ways to better yourself and find happiness and understanding in today's society. This is an open forum where comments, talking points, concerns and discussion about topics are encouraged. Most content is focused towards single men's issues but may be applicable to others. I focus on viewing many issues from multiple or under represented angles."
        },
        "country": "US"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't see why snippet is being left out of the response for my API call.

Comment: Your code says `&part=id&snippet&` but the yt example says `&part=id, snippet&` (with ", " escaped to %2C%20)

Comment: Damn. Rookie mistake. Thanks. The id parameter is a comma seperated list. I missed that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is slightly incorrect.

Your code says `&part=id&snippet&` but the YouTube example says `&part=id, snippet&` (with ", " escaped to %2C%20).